# HttpClient sending parameter null

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send data to an api with HttpClient but parameter I'm sending keeps received as 0.

What am I doing wrong here? It's my first usage of HttpClient so it's quite possible I mixed things or made some rookie mistake.

Path is correct, I can get results from Postman.

Code I'm using is this;

```
static async Task GetActivityList()
{
    string uri = "/api/ExtraNet/GetActivityList";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    int SalesPersonId = 553;
    string token = my token value is here;

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:16513/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var postData = "{\"SalesPersonId=\":\""+SalesPersonId+"\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent( "{\"SalesPersonId=\":\"" + SalesPersonId + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") ;
    var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:16513/api/ExtraNet/GetActivityList", stringContent);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Why is postData and content created?

Comment: Probably left it uncommented while trying  different ways to send the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I managed to send the parameter this way

```
string uri = "/api/ExtraNet/GetActivityList";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            int SalesPersonId = 553;
            string token = "";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:16513/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("SalesPersonId","553")
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Sending the parameters as `FormUrlEncodedContent` did the trick.